# Работа с массивом, сортировка, создание поля и изменение значения

Tags: массивы, javascript

Всем привет.
Хочу вывести категории с "алфавитом", т.е. отсортировать их и вывести что-то вроде пункта, в котором находиться первый символ значения ключа.

К примеру, есть массив

```
[{name: 'слово'},{name: 'слово'},{name: 'название'},{name: 'имя'}]
```

Сначала я его сортирую так:

```
var catalogSort = catalog.sort(function(one, two) {
    if (one.name < two.name) return -1;
    if (one.name > two.name) return 1;
    return 0;
});
```

Теперь добавляю новое поле с первым символом:

```
var used = [];
for(var x = 0; x < catalogSort.length; x++) {
    used[x] = {val: catalogSort[x].name.slice(0, 1), name: catalogSort[x].name}
}
```

Получаю такой массив:

```
[{val: 'с', name: 'слово'},{val: 'с', name: 'слово'},{val: 'н', name: 'название'},{val: 'и', name: 'имя'}]
```

Теперь проблема в том, что мне нужно поле val изменить на false в том случае, если значение уже встречается в массиве. Как такое реализовать, чтобы получить такой массив?

```
[{val: 'с', name: 'слово'},{val: 'false', name: 'слово'},{val: 'н', name: 'название'},{val: 'и', name: 'имя'}]
```

Comment: Как-то нелогично сначала плодить одинаковые поля, а затем как в фильме «Горец» эпично кричать «Может быть только один!».

Я бы предложил изменить структуру на два уровня вложенности:

    {
        "и": [ {name: 'имя'}],
        "н": [ {name: 'название'}],
        "с": [ {name: 'слово'},{name: 'слово'}],
    }

Comment: Хочется просто одним циклом потом все выбирать, а с двумя придется плодить два цикла. А так я просто проверку бы сделал, существуют ли поле val или равно оно false. 
Ну а так да, я уже думал о том варианте, но хочу напоследок его оставить.

Comment: Цикл один, если не считать сортировку: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sergiks/rbn3jcra/)